# Using Node.js, how can I add values from a column in the CSV file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I am relatively new to node.js and am doing a little side project and have gotten stuck. I am taking an unzipped csv file and am trying to add the values that are in the specified column using node.

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var stream = fs.createReadStream("my.csv");

var sum = 0;

csv
     .fromStream(stream, { headers: [, , "total_master_images", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ] })
     .on("data", function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      })
     .on("end", function() {
         console.log("--------------------------------");
      });
```

And some of the output:

```
{ total_master_images: 'total_master_images' }
{ total_master_images: '1' }
{ total_master_images: '2' }
{ total_master_images: '2' }
{ total_master_images: '2' }
{ total_master_images: '466' }
{ total_master_images: '990' }
{ total_master_images: '5953' }
{ total_master_images: '1473' }
```

I also can't get rid of the column header when being printed, but that isn't that big of deal. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, the `data` event happens whenever a row is parsed, and `end` happens when they're all finished. What you can do is add to sum inside of `data`, then log out the sum in `end`.

```
 .on("data", function(data) {
     // Convert from string to number
     var num = Number(data.total_master_images)

     // If the number is not valid, it'll end up being `NaN`, so check if it's not NaN first
     if (!Number.isNaN(num)) {
       sum += num
     }
  })
 .on("end", function() {
     console.log("The sum is " + sum);
  });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much, you're a life saver.